# Need to fix main account - can login but cant do much

Tags: permissions, login, launcher, users

I've been a Ubuntu user about 2 years. I am using the same user account and have most defaults for upgrading etc and have the current version and updates.

I can login to my account but can't get anything to work really as the Launcher does not appear. My shortcut to system monitor works and I can access the System settings however once I open that window I can't close it. The icons like time, sound, in the upper right corner are not there anymore.

The only thing I did today was I changed my background to use my pictures folder and turned off the launcher 'hide'. The background picture didn't change so I went back in and did it again. I couldn't close out of that window and I couldn't open anything else. I opened a guest account and shut down from there. I could re-login as my main user but the launcher didn't appear and I couldn't do anything else...but I could create another admin account.

So, I have admin status but everything on the computer belongs to my main user account, so I can't delete anything. I'd rather not start over with a new account, but when I login as my main user I can't do anything!! Help...